# How can I pass configuration options to yarn/npm

Tags: node.js, reactjs, yarnpkg

I have a react app and server that provides REST services to the react app. In development the react app runs on port 3000 and the server on port 3001. 
To support this the package.json file has proxy statement "proxy": "http://localhost:3001"

However in production this isn't wanted so I like a means of controlling this from "yarn start" so that I need only one package.json that uses the proxy in development but not in production. Thanks in advance

Comment: You shouldn't need to worry about it - try deploying your app to production and you should see it works fine with the proxy in your package.json

Answer (score 0):

> so that I need only one package.json

you should only have one package.json...

You probably have something that looks like

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "webpack-dev-server --host 0.0.0.0 ..."
  ...
}
```

in your `package.json` - when you run `yarn start`, ^ that is what is actually being run. That's not something you would run in production though. If you want something else to run in production, add another item to `scripts` that runs your express (?) app directly (something like `node /path/to/index.js` is probably close).